# Calculate Naive Baysian classifier

Tags: probability, naive-bayes

I'm preparing Dell EMC Associate data science certificate. The following is one of the mock questions and I'm having problem to calculate it by hand and need help. The correct answer is $Y=1$, $probability = 4/54$ and $Y=0$, $probability = 1/54$
However, I'm not able to get correct answer.

[image]

Consider the training data set shown in above table. What are the classifications ($Y=0$ or $Y=1$), and the probabilities of the classifications for the tuple $X (0,0,1)$ using Naive Bayesian classifier?

Calculations:

$$
P(Y=1)P(X_1=0|Y=1)P(X_2=0|Y=1)P(X_3=1|Y=1)  \\ P(Y=0)P(X_1=0|Y=0)P(X_2=0|Y=0)P(X_3=1|Y=0)
$$

\begin{align}
P(Y=1) &= 9/18  \\
P(Y=0) &= 9/18  \\
P(X_1=0|Y=1) &= 2/9  \\
P(X_2=0|Y=1) &= 1/9  \\
P(X_3=1|Y=1) &= 2/9  
\end{align}

But,

$$\frac 2 9 \times \frac 1 9 \times \frac 2 9 \times \frac 9 {18} \ne \frac 5 {54}$$

Answer (score 2):

** CORRECTION - the corrected answer is for the tuple (1,0,0), not for (0, 0, 1) -  typo on the question

$$P(Y=0|X_1=1,X_2=0,X_3=0)\\= P(Y=0)\times P(X_1=1|Y=0)\times P(X_2=0|Y=0)\times P(X_3=0|Y=0)\\=1/2\times2/3\times1/3\times2/3=4/54$$

$$P(Y=1|X_1=1,X_2=0,X_3=0)\\= P(Y=1)\times P(X_1=1|Y=0)\times P(X_2=0|Y=0)\times P(X_3=0|Y=0)\\=3/6\times1/3\times 1/3\times1/3=1/54$$

$4/54 > 1/54$ => the correct answer is Classification $Y = 0$, $Probability = 4/54$

[image]

Comment: Are you answering the question or correcting it?  If you are correcting it you should edit the question and not put it in an answer.

Comment: Being new to the community, somehow it didn't allow me to edit the question even I created an account and verified my email address. Thank you Mooncrater for the editing. I later figured out the answer by myself.